# C++ interface inheritance problem

Tags: c++

Hey, i'm trying to create a c++ stomp client,
my client constructor is :

```
Client(std::string &server, short port, std::string &login, std::string &pass, Listener &listener);
```

it gets a listener object which when Listener is the following interface :

```
class Listener {

    virtual void message(StmpMessage message) =0;
};
```

now i attempt to instantiate a client in a test class :

```
class test : public virtual Listener {
public:
    void message(StmpMessage message) {
        message.prettyPrint();
    }
     int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {

        Client client("127.0.0.1", 61613, *this);
        return 0;
    }


};
```

i'm sending this to the client because this is a listener object,
i get the following error :

```
/Users/mzruya/Documents/STOMPCPP/main.cpp:18: error: no matching function for call to 'Client::Client(const char [10], int, test&)'
/Users/mzruya/Documents/STOMPCPP/Client.h:43: note: candidates are: Client::Client(std::string&, short int, std::string&, std::string&, Listener&)
/Users/mzruya/Documents/STOMPCPP/Client.h:37: note:                 Client::Client(const Client&)
```

Comment: What part of the compiler error do you not understand?

Comment: Also, since this is c++ and not Java, the main method does not belong in the test class scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because you're passing the wrong parameters to the `Client` c'tor …

`Client(std::string &server, short port, std::string &login, std::string &pass, Listener &listener);`

and you call it

`Client client("127.0.0.1", 61613, *this);`

… you missed the `pass` and `login` parameters. Your listener is fine. The problem is *not* related to inheritance.

Comment: oppps, silly me, and i wasted the last half hour trying to understand what's wrong with my understanding of interfaces :-)

Comment: Is passing a string which is not defined anywhere legal ? I mean doing `Client("127.0.0.1", ...)` will really work ? I am asking since the Constructor expects a &.

Comment: @Muggen: The reference must be const in this scenario, good catch.

Comment: @DeadMG, also another Q : How can he pass `*this` ? Can he really do that ? I thought that it is not yet initialized, and that you couldn't use `this` outside the object's local scope (inside the object methods). I hope my Q is clear :S

Comment: @Muggen: He doesn't define main as a static method, so it is an instance method and therefore `this` is perfectly available.

Comment: @DeadMG, hm but it doesn't run on my pc. plz See my answer and plz comment appropriately. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have something wrong on your code

First, afaik you can't define the main inside a class. The program compiles on my pc (using gcc) but it throws

`_start':(.text+0x18): undefined reference to main'`

Second, as Alexander said on his post you do not pass the correct number of arguments on your constructor getting those errors.

Third, the way you pass arguments on your Constructor is wrong. References require an `lvalue`. If you want to send them an `rvalue` you need to define your Constructor arguments as

`Client(const std::string &server, short port, const std::string &login, const std::string &pass)`

Stroustup's book states that this will be interpreted as

```
std::string temp = std::string("127.0.0.1");
server = temp;
```

simply-speaking - a temp object will be created to satisfy the Reference.

As you see I removed the `Listener &listener` Arguments because **I don't know** (and tbh I don't think) if you can pass `this` as an argument. Maybe someone could clarify-fix that.

if you want to pass your arguments in the Constructor as strings (eg. `Client("127.0.0.1" , ...)`) then I guess you would have to do something like that :

```
std::string hostname = "127.0.0.1";
std::string log = "UserName";
std::string pw = "PassWord";
Client client(hostname, 61613, log , pw);
```

and of course define your Constructor as

```
Client(std::string &server, short port, std::string &login, std::string &pass)
{
}
```

Maybe someone could clarify whats happening with the `this` thingy, and if and how you can do that.

---

**edit:**

This is the code I used in my pc to come up with all that. Hope it is ok.

```
#include <iostream>
//Ghost Class
class StmpMessage
{
    public:
    void prettyPrint()
    {
    }
};

class Listener 
{
    virtual void message(StmpMessage message) = 0;
};

class Client : public virtual Listener 
{
    public:
        Client(std::string &server, short port, 
               std::string &login, std::string &pass)
        {
        }

        void message(StmpMessage message) 
        {
            message.prettyPrint();
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string hostname = "127.0.0.1";
    std::string log = "UserName";
    std::string pw = "PassWord";
    Client client(hostname, 61613, log , pw);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Of course you can pass this as an argument. That's the point. `this` is a perfectly valid pointer, usable in any places where a normal pointer is.

Comment: @DeadMG, thanks for answer, if anything else is correct in the post, then how can you do it ? If you could please look after the edit on the bottom and clarify I would appreciate. Thanks. This code I show does not compile, nor any combination of `this *this` and similarly for constructor (`shotgun programming`), and it gives `so4.cpp:33: error: invalid use of ‘this’ in non-member function` Cheers

Comment: The `this` pointer points to the current object- and you're trying to use it in a non-object-orientated function. How were you expecting it to work?

Comment: Thats what I mean. Ok. From what I understood I thought that you were saying that you could do that. Now it is clear. thanks for clarifying.